# Condition membership of experience site based on permission set for users created with createUser handler code

Tags: user, future, dmlexception, okta, registration-handler

We have created handler code which works great for a community when the community is set to allow membership based on the profile that is also assigned by the handler code. We have a requirement though that requires membership for new self-service users to be based on permission set only. That is not working for us.

We are using Okta for auth with an OIDC connection. The handler code builds up a newUser "object" and then performs an insert for the new user, adds a permission set for the user, and then returns newUser to the reg handler so that it can log the user in. This is the end of the method creating the user:

```apex
try{
    insert newUser;
    System.debug('Inserted User Record===' + newUser.Id);
    assignPermissionSet(newUser.Id, personaInfo.PermissionSet_Name__c);
    return newUser;
} 
catch(DmlException e){
    return null;
}
```

`assignPermissionSet` is an `@future` method, but the same result happens without `@future`. The `newUser` object logs as follows once it is returned back to the reg handler.

```json
{Username=test.permset@gmail.com.org1.prof, 
    Email=test.permset@gmail.com, 
    LastName=Test, 
    FirstName=Permset, 
    Alias=tpermset, 
    LanguageLocaleKey=en_US, 
    LocaleSidKey=en_US,EmailEncodingKey=UTF-8,
    TimeZoneSidKey=America/New_York,
    ProfileId=xxer00000xxNjWbAAK,
    ContactId=xx3r0000xxtKgh4AAC,
    FederationIdentifier=xxu1cs14pfsxxZdJN0h8.prof, 
    Id=xx5r0000xx7x4ADAAY}
```

The reg handler then returns that same `newUser` object. The user is created with all proper fields, and the right permission set. When experience site membership is based on profile, the user can enter the community--albeit with some rendering delays perhaps because of permission set delays.

When I remove the profile from membership options for the community, and only allow membership based on the permission set assigned by the reg handler, the user does not get created. I do get this DML error:

```
(5156874766)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[278]|System.DmlException: 
Insert failed. First exception on row 0; 
first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object 
is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): 
PermissionSetAssignment, original object: Contact: []
```

The above user object is still returned to the reg handler and logged as shown above. But the user record is not created and the users themselves are redirected to the error page established for the auth provider with the following params:

> /?ErrorCode=NO_ACCESS&
> ErrorDescription=User%20was%20not%20authorized%20for%20the%20community&
> ProviderId=0xOrxxx0004xox&
> startURL=%2FUserAppName%2Fs%2F

I did expect that there might be some delay with assigning the permission sets, and we could just use the error page to tell the user "just a few more moments" while we create their user. But it is as if the whole process of user creation, let alone permission assignment, stops when the user is rejected from the community. I thought perhaps there is something we could add to the `newUser` object above that would let the reg handler know that this user will have the right permSet when the user is finally created. But I can't find anything on that point.

Any guidance or thoughts on this is greatly appreciated. We are stuck.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug - open a case with Support. Conceptually this alleged bug is due to a catch-22: any operation for/on behalf of this user that touches the community must be authorized...but the authorization is gated by the community membership. Still, it shouldn't roll back the user create.

Comment: @identigral - I did open a case and it turns out there was an exception I missed in the error log. See edited post above. They would not fix it for me of course, but did give me this link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315345&type=1. I will post if I get to the exact solution, but any guidance is appreciated as I think the exact scenario is not covered in the doc.